# which one is better wget or scp to copy files from one server to other?

Tags: ssh, copy, scp

I have to copy my all projects from one server to other.

which one is better options : wget or scp ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `scp`. `wget` is only useful to retrieve files using HTTP or FTP.

Comment: I am not satisfied by your answer. I use `wget` way more than `scp`. Is scp better in every scenario ?, isn't it more slow. What if I just want to copy a large .zip file over, and I don't need the scp security?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales If your file is available through FTP or HTTP(S), then use wget. But you don't normally use those protocols to copy files from one server to another one.

Comment: If security is not a big deal, I usually try the two, and cancel the one with lower speed. As an example, i was moving a large file to EC2 and found out that i was getting twice as much speed of SCP from from local to remote, compared to wget on remote EC2

Comment: Actually, if you recommend `scp`, you should mention that for large (number of) files, `rsync` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer wget since it's much faster than scp. I've always experienced wget 5 times faster than scp.

Say, I have a gigabyte network. If I try to copy a large file through scp, the max rate may be 10MB/s while it can be as fast as 50MB/s with wget.

The problem is wget can only be used through http. But it's easy if you try with SimpleHTTPServer from python.

Answer (score 0):

If I need files from outside of my network I will use wget.

If the files I need are within my network I will use scp.

Comment: You should add some explanations WHY you do it that way.